# GUI for designing Windows 10 apps? Or is it only through XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-universal

Like many others, I'm learning how to create Windows 10 apps with VS2015. Recently an opportunity came up to develop a simple application to run in a 7" Windows 10 tablet. Instead of paying someone to do it, I decided to give it a try and do the work myself.

Using the [Create a "Hello, world" app (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-xaml-universal) tutorial, I began creating the most basic app.

It seems straightforward, but is there a way to drag-and-drop controls to the mainpage, similar to webforms or windows forms?

Thanks.

Comment: For WPF there's a visual designer, but it uses fixed positioning for every thing you drag onto it. I prefer writing the XAML by hand, it's not that hard (especially not if you ever used any other markup language) and there are some MVVM frameworks that will make it fun to do XAML.

Comment: Adding the XAML by hand shouldn't be that hard, but how do I know what controls I have available?

Comment: Included with Visual Studio 2015, but a separate program, is Blend which is geared more for designing and animating the UI. Have you tried using that? You should be able to right click a .xaml file in the Solution Explorer and click "Design in Blend..."

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a bug right now, but if you go into your App's Properties, under Application, change the Target version from "Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10586)" to "Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240)". This should bring your designer back.

Comment: I changed it, but I still can't see the designer. And the toolbox is empty ("no usable controls in this group").

Comment: I just noticed that the target device is set to `Remote Machine`, and I don't have any of the `Emulator` alternatives as shown [here](https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/484/posts/23122/image/univeral-app-switch-startup-project.png). Maybe that's why I can't see the designer?

Comment: I assume I can't see the designer because I have Windows 7 and I don't have a Windows 10 device to debug the app. Is this correct?

Comment: @rbhatup To develop for Windows 10, you do have to be on Windows 10. 7 doesn't have access to the 10 API required to create the universal apps.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your MainPage.xaml or any .xaml file, select **open in blend** or **design in blend** as the case may be. It will open your project main page in Microsoft blend, an application meant for designers.